# Xpath path help

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have the following XML:

```
<products>
    <product>       
        <name>Flat Panel Monitor</name>
        <code>LS123</code>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <group>Color</group>
                <values>
                    <value>Red</value>
                    <value>Blue</value>
                    <value>Green</value>
                </values>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
                <group>Warranty</group>
                <values>
                    <value>5 Year</value>
                </values>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </product>
</products>
```

What Xpath would i use to get all value's with the attribute node with the group node value of "Color" ? A standard Xpath of `/product/attributes/attribute/values/value` would return all value's including value's from within the Warranty group but i need to keep them separate.

I guess in pseudocode what i'm saying is get all "value" where the parent node "values" is a sibling of the node "group" with the value "Color" - hopefully this is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I love the fact that this question has engendered three totally different working answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use square brackets to filter the nodes, thus: 
`/product/attributes/attribute[group='Color']/values/value`

Comment: By "square brackets" Paul meant a **predicate**.

Comment: Thanks Josh, that's quite a valuable addition to the answer.  I should have included the terminology so that he could look it up.

Answer (score 3):

You require only those `value` nodes that have a `group` 'uncle' of `Color`, so put that as a condition on the xpath you have already worked out:

```
/product/attributes/attribute/values/value[../../group = 'Color']
```

This says that for a `value` node to be valid, it must have a parent with a parent with a child with value `Color`.

Comment: As proposed by Paul Butcher, it's more correct to apply a predicate on their common ancestor `<attribute/>`. It's also more performant, as the engine doesn't need to go deep into the tree then back up to the ancestor.

Comment: @Josh, yes that is a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option:

`//value[ancestor::attribute[group='Color']]`

Answer (score 0):

```
//values[preceding-sibling::group[text()="Color"]]/value
```